# Extend stay in Canada after expiration of Working Holiday visa without degree

Tags: visa, canada, working-holiday-visas

I just got approved for the Working Holiday visa for Canada and unfortunately I can get a work permit that is only 6 months long as I have Italian citizenship (so unlucky, to think that it's the only country in the list to have less than 12 months...).

I would like to stay in Canada for longer and maybe settle there. Would there be a possibility to extend the work permit and eventually get permanent residency considering that I do not have a bachelor's degree?

Comment: You can find an employer who is ready to sponsor you and file an LMIA on your behalf. That's one of the many possible ways to get Permanent residency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One year and a half later I have the answer.

If your employer doesn't want to sponsor you with an [LMIA](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=163&top=17), you still have other easier options to extend your stay, even **without a bachelor's degree**.

Tha catch is you need some **money**.

You can apply for a repeat participation of the Working Holiday with the help of a **[Recognized Organization](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/exemption-codes/international-experience/canadian-interests-reciprocal-employment-international-experience-canada-recognized-organizations-foreign-youth.html)** - even if Canada does not normally allow that for your country of origin.

With a Recognized Organization, anybody from *almost* any country can apply for:

- [Working Holiday](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/eligibility.asp#working_holiday)
- [Young Professional](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/eligibility.asp#youngProfessionals)
- [International Co-op (Internship)](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/eligibility.asp#coop)

The requirements for the listed visas are the same as if you applied by yourself.
The only difference is that you'll have to pay a fee to the Recognized Organization and that can range from $500 CAD to $3000 CAD or more (it increases a bit every year).

Other (more difficult) options where higher education is **not** required are:

- [Canadian Experience Class](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/canadian-experience-class.html) (you need 1 year of continuous skilled work experience in Canada)
- [Federal Skilled Worker](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/federal-skilled-workers.html)

There are also many other immigration programs specific to each province that can help you.

All of the above **does not** apply to Quebec.